# PowerShell/CLI: “Foreach” loop with multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to get my brain round something and on the verge of head explosion.
I have a list of data listing usernames, and virtual machines.

for example:

```
username      servername
bob.lazar     abc001
bob.lazar     abc002
peter.bob     ght004
bob.lazar     abc006
```

I need to collate the user data so I can email them listing.  if I loop through and email it would mail bob 3x times, but I need to email bob once with 3 server names.  I assume I need to put the data into a multidimential array and loop through but just don't know where to begin.

Comment: `$data | group username | % { do something }`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't fully understand the problem but I'm pretty sure you are looking for the GROUP cmdlet.
Pipe a collection to it and specify what property you want to group things by and then all the elements are available as a GROUP property

```
JPS> dir |group extension |? Name -eq ".txt" | % Group


    Directory: C:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         6/2/2016   8:23 PM          57930 foo.txt
-a----       12/21/2015   8:00 PM           8265 ModuleSessions.ps1.t
-a----        3/15/2016   6:26 PM             51 num.txt
-a----         6/6/2015   6:55 PM           2390 t2.txt
```

Alternatively, you can use -AsHashtable to return a hashtable with the property as a key

```
JPS> (dir |group Extension -AsHashTable)[".txt"]


    Directory: C:\temp


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         6/2/2016   8:23 PM          57930 foo.txt
-a----       12/21/2015   8:00 PM           8265 ModuleSessions.ps1.txt
-a----        3/15/2016   6:26 PM             51 num.txt
-a----         6/6/2015   6:55 PM           2390 t2.txt
```

Experiment with those.

Comment: I need to email the user in question a list of server names, I can look up the user against AD to get the email address, and email them all the server names that match.

Comment: I'm gathering I can use group, then use a foreach to loop through the names